# Push Notifications using GCM

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have Python2.7 and installed this modules: feedparser, Kivy, plyer and setuptools-17.0.

I am developing a simple Android app with a web-viewer inside and the core functionality is that I parse a simple XML and whenever a new feed is posted I want the user to receive a push-notification on his Android Device.

I have my own web-server and also I've tried different push services on the web, but they are trials or very limited. Can someone please give me guidance on how to manage the push-service? Maybe a couple of hints on which modules I need to get my job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a couple of services that interact with Google's GCM

You will need a callable URL that can process the registrations of the device when the app is first started.

You also need to send a JSON file with the data to be sent when you have a new notification to be sent.

All of this is fairly straightforward in Python.

You can get more information here.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

You will need a Google account to setup GCM